# How to get current route config in navigationEnd event?

Tags: angular

How can I get the static route path of the current router-outlet component, what was activated by angular in router events?

I need it in app.component, because it would be redundant if I have to do in all component with activatedRoute.snapshot

```
self.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        //I need here the path of route E.G '/page/:id/' from root

    }
});
```

Update:
In routing:

```
export const MAIN_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomePage },
    { path: 'something', component: SomethingComponent },
    { path: 'page/:id', component: PageComponent }, //if the url is 'example.com/page/someId' than, I want to get the "path" field of this object and if I change the page, I need that inside the router event above. 
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a hacky solution for his:

```
    let path = '';

    self.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        console.log(event);

        if(event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
            if(event.snapshot) {
                if(event.snapshot.routeConfig && event.snapshot.routeConfig.path) {
                    path = path == '' ? event.snapshot.routeConfig.path : [event.snapshot.routeConfig.path, path].join('/');
                }
            }
        }

        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            //save the path, and clear it.

            self.path = path;
            path = '';
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActivationEnd` event has `snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot` property. You can find the path in `event.snapshot.config.path` property.

Based on your router setup you might have multiple `ActivationEnd` events during one navigation though, usually the first one is the one in which you are interested.

[Angular ActivationEnd event docs](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivationEnd)

Comment: Actually no, I want to get 'page/:id'

Comment: How can I detect which one is the first event when is subscribed to the events?

Comment: With some boolean property in your service which you reset when you receive `NavigationStart`. Or with some operator magic on `Router.events` stream which will create a pair of `ActivationEnd` and `NavigationEnd`.